# Django: How to use filter() or not based at optional param?

Tags: python, django, django-2.2

As you can see in this url `city` param is optional:

```
re_path(r'all/(?P<category>\w+)/(?P<page_num>\w+)/?/(?P<city>\d+)?', views.show_all_objects, name="show-all-objects")
```

**views.py:**

```
def show_all_objects(request, category, page_num, city=''):
    if category == 'restaurants':
        objects = Item.objects.instance_of(Restaurant)
    elif category == 'sportfitness':
        objects = Item.objects.instance_of(SportFitness)
    elif category == 'carservice':
        objects = Item.objects.instance_of(CarService)
    elif category == 'beautysalon':
        objects = Item.objects.instance_of(BeautySalon)
    elif category == 'fastfood':
        objects = Item.objects.instance_of(FastFood)
    elif category == 'carwash':
        objects = Item.objects.instance_of(CarWash)
    elif category == 'fun':
        objects = Item.objects.instance_of(Fun)
    elif category == 'other':
        objects = Item.objects.instance_of(Other)

    paginator = Paginator(objects, 2)
    objects = paginator.get_page(page_num)

    context = {
        'objects': objects,
        'category': category,
        'page_num': page_num,
    }

    return render(request, 'show_all_objects.html', context)
```

I want if city param is set to add `.filter(city=city)`, I can do it with `if/else` but it doesn't follow DRY principles.

Comment: How does it "not follow DRY principle" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would be wrong with the following?:

```
def show_all_objects(request, category, page_num, city=''):
    if category == 'restaurants':
        objects = Item.objects.instance_of(Restaurant)
    elif category == 'sportfitness':
        objects = Item.objects.instance_of(SportFitness)
    elif category == 'carservice':
        objects = Item.objects.instance_of(CarService)
    elif category == 'beautysalon':
        objects = Item.objects.instance_of(BeautySalon)
    elif category == 'fastfood':
        objects = Item.objects.instance_of(FastFood)
    elif category == 'carwash':
        objects = Item.objects.instance_of(CarWash)
    elif category == 'fun':
        objects = Item.objects.instance_of(Fun)
    elif category == 'other':
        objects = Item.objects.instance_of(Other)

    # The only difference is these two lines:
    if city:
        objects = objects.filter(city=city)    

    paginator = Paginator(objects, 2)
    objects = paginator.get_page(page_num)

    context = {
        'objects': objects,
        'category': category,
        'page_num': page_num,
    }

    return render(request, 'show_all_objects.html', context)
```

Answer (score 3):

try to use dictionary to map the parameter for the instance_of method.

```
def show_all_objects(request, category, page_num, city=''):

    params_map = {
        'restaurants': Restaurant,
        'sportfitness': SportFitness,
        'carservice': CarService,
        'beautysalon': BeautySalon,
        'fastfood': FastFood,
        'carwash': CarWash,
        'fun': Fun,
        'other': Other,
    }

    objects = Item.objects.instance_of(params_map.get(category))

    # If city is provided
    if city:
        objects = objects.filter(city=city)    

    paginator = Paginator(objects, 2)
    objects = paginator.get_page(page_num)

    context = {
        'objects': objects,
        'category': category,
        'page_num': page_num,
    }

    return render(request, 'show_all_objects.html', context)
```

Comment: Lol, thank you very much, this would help me and to many other places in my app!

Comment: instead of if-elif-else, using dictionary is much more readable and pythonic.